# how to stop the command from taking in input?

Tags: c++, string

In this code, how to stop this code from taking input, in earlier edition of HUBBARD its written use Ctrl+D or Ctrl+z but its not working. please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char line[80];
   while(*line)
   {
      cin>>line;
      if(*line) cout<<" "<<line<<" "<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried `Ctrl + C`?

Comment: \0 is not working 
yes, Ctrl + c is working.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check of whether EOF of the stream has been reached needs to be done a bit differently.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char line[80];
   while(cin>>line)
   {
      cout << " " << line << " " << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

`cin >> line` will evaluate to `false` when EOF is reached or if there are any other errors. Hence the `while` loop will break at that time.

If you really need to read a line, as the variable `line` suggests, don't use `cin >> line`. Use `std::getline` instead. `cin >> line` will not read whitespace characters. `std::getline` will read whitespace characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::string line;
   while( getline(cin, line))
   {
      cout << " " << line << " " << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can stop the while loop by using the any value(like 0, $ in this case) with not equal comparison operator.

```
 while(*line!='0')
```

when you will enter the 0 it will terminate.
or by using $

```
 while(*line!='$')
```

when you will enter the $ it will terminate.
Full code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main() {

 char line[80];
 while(*line!='$')
 {
  cin>>line;
  if(*line) cout<<" "<<line<<" "<<endl;
 }
 return 0;      
}
```