# C++: If I want to enter a series of number into an array without being limited by the amount of number I need to enter. How should I do this?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
    int A[10]
    for (int i=0; i< 10; i++){
        cin >> A[i] ;
    }
```

I want the users to be able to enter a list of numbers, but right now I have to type in 10 numbers to break the loop. How can I make it so I can stop whenever I want?
I'm a beginner and I am thankful for your time and help!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273903/how-to-stop-the-command-from-taking-in-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you should use a vector, your array will resize while you push back.

```
std::vector<int> name;
```

[You can find more about it here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Otherwise you will have to make a function to resize...Vector basically does the same thing for you.

Your code would be than:

```
        int input;
        std::vector<int> A;
        for (int i=0; i< 10; i++){
            cin >> input;
            A.push_back(input);
        }
```

To break the loop you could ask a question for the user to break the loop and based on the answer you could break the loop.

Comment: Is there any way to use an array? I am practicing sorting, and my function is based on array. Also, thanks!

Comment: Oh i understand now, yeah you can. What you have to do is to create a function that handles that for you but than you have to work with pointers to do it effectively. Here is a exemple of a resisable function: https://sites.google.com/site/pdcppnotes/arrays/dynamically-resize-array

Answer (score 0):

you can write the following commands:

```
int data;
int i =0;
while(cin>>data && i!=10){
    arr[i++] = data;
}
```

Here **cin>>data** will take input from the file until the file ends.
You can change it to

```
cin>>data!=-1
```

where this command will stop taking integer values from the user when they enter -1.

Comment: This will overflow the array if someone types in 11 values.  You should `while(i<10 && cin>>data){`

Comment: But the person wants to stop taking inputs whenever they want, so if we restrict it to 10 then it won't be possible to do so.

Comment: But the array `arr` is only 10 so what happens when you put in 11 values?

Comment: okay, i understood your point. In case, if only 10 elements need to be entered, then we can put up the condition that you wrote earlier. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: And if more than 10 elements need to be entered, how do you know how big the array needs to be?  That's when dynamically allocating the array becomes useful.

Comment: so i thought that the question must be talking about dynamic array, or undefined size. in that case we can use a vector and push elements into it until the end of file.